# Python Discord Add Role

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to create a bot that adds a role to users based on a set of criteria.  I have the user ID's stored in a MySQL database.

My add role function:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def add_role(ctx, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
     await client.get_guild(ctx.guild.id).fetch_member(member).add_roles(role)
```

I later call this function and try to pass in the users discord ID that is stored in a database. Value "d" from the array is the stored discord ID.

```py
@client.command()
async def daily_task(ctx):
    try:
        message = ""
        connectDB()
        cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
        stmt = """very long sql statement"""
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        for a, b, c, d, e, f, g ,h ,i, j, k, l in cursor.fetchall():
            print(d) #troubleshooting
            if d != 0:
                await add_role(ctx, d, "VEP")
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
    except Error as e:
        await ctx.send(e)
        print(e)
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Comment: Can you replace `user.add_roles(role)` with `client.get_user(user).add_roles(role)` and try running it?

Comment: @SuneeshJacob "AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'add_roles'"
I take it I might need to swap user class out for member?

Comment: Yes, you need to use member object. User object is just the object of the Discord user, and it doesn't have any information about any particular server, whilst member object is related to a particular server.

Comment: If you have the server id then you can try something like this: `client.get_guild('<server id>').fetch_member(user).add_roles(role)`

Comment: @SuneeshJacob Thanks. I tried that and updated the OP with my current code and new error. AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Comment: i think i am asking to try too many things (because i can't run it on my computer right now), but for the last time can you try `get_member` instead of `fetch_member`? i.e., can you replace `client.get_guild(ctx.guild.id).fetch_member(member).add_roles(role)` with `client.get_guild(ctx.guild.id).get_member(member).add_roles(role)` and try running it? I think it might most definitely work.

Comment: Appreciate your help! "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def add_role(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
    server = client.get_guild(12345678912344566)
    user = await server.fetch_member(member)
    await user.add_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="VEP"))
```

```
async def daily_task(ctx):
    try:
        message = ""
        connectDB()
        cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
        stmt = """sql string"""
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        for a, b, c, d, e, f, g ,h ,i, j, k, l in cursor.fetchall():
            if d != 0:
                print(d)
                if (4 + g + i) - l > 0:
                    await add_role(ctx, d, "VEP") 
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
    except Error as e:
        await ctx.send(e)
        print(e)
```